# How to add a Pause and Stop function to my Javascript Text to Speech

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I cannot seem to get the Text to Speech, to pause and stop, I was wondering if anyone knew.

My Simple Text to Speech function

```
function TextToSpeech()
{
   const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let convert = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

    speech.text = convert;
   
    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;
   
    speech.voice = voices[1];
   
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}


function Pause()
{
    speech.Pause;
}


function Stop()
{
    speech.Stop;
}
```

Comment: Currently, I cannot write code to solve your problem, but if your code is correct, then the problem you have is that the `speech` inside the `Pause` and `Stop` functions is out of the scope. To solve it, move the `const speech` outside the function `TextToSpeech` and the script will work though.

Comment: Did you mean speech.Pause(), speech.Stop() ?  It won’t work unless you invoke those methods (with the parentheses)

Comment: 1) stop is a method of speech recognition; you could use pause() or cancel().
2) These are methods of speechSynthesis and not the utterance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment I've changed and added to your code to show how the methods work.

```js
function textToSpeech()
{
   const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let convert = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

    speech.text = convert;
   
    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;
   
    speech.voice = voices[1];
   
    speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}


function pause()
{
    speechSynthesis.pause();
}


function stop()
{
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
}

speakBtn.addEventListener('click', textToSpeech);
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pause);
cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', stop);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="speakBtn" value="Speak">
<input type="button" id="pauseBtn" value="Pause">
<input type="button" id="cancelBtn" value="Cancel">
<p id="text">Text to speak goes here</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, but also the pause button doesn't seem to work, it only stops the text-to-speech, but it doesn't continue when you click on it, is there a way the pause to work?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You can use speechSynthesis.resume() to restart after a pause, perhaps behind a 'Resume' button.

Comment: Thank you again, you really helped me out